# How do I import different JS files into layout for different haml views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra, haml

Typically, I'd include those in each haml file, but because the main layout includes jquery, all new js files have to appear AFTER the jquery src.
How do I to include different JS files based on the haml currently being used?

So basically I got:

```
haml :login_signup, :layout => :'main'
```

And from the login_signup haml file, I would like to pass the name of the JS file to be launched from the :main haml file.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Haml's documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter) you should be able to include the scripts on the haml files doing something like this:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript",
    :src  => "javascripts/script"}
```

I'd highly recommend looking into using webpack to handle js dependancies and creating bundles. It'll make it a lot easier to manage which js files get loaded when. I found [this post](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/02/a-detailed-introduction-to-webpack/) pretty good at explaining why to choose webpack.

Comment: I am looking after the solution where I can deinfe the source of the JS file inside the haml file so it is read by the main layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditions in the layout file.

```
-if request.path_info.include? '/some/path'
  =# include your scripts
```

Alternatively, you can just put the script files at the bottom of your page's haml itself.